# Mongoose can't recognize my 2dsphere index

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add `2dSphere` index for my field `startLocation` exists in `tourSchema`. Here how it looks below

```
   startLocation: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Point',
        enum: ['Point']
      },
      coordinates: [Number],
      address: String,
      description: String
    }
```

And you can also see below what and how I've added indexes on this Schema

```
tourSchema.index({price:1,ratingsAverage:-1});
tourSchema.index({slug:1});
tourSchema.index({ startLocation: '2dsphere' });
```

Unfortunately `Mongodb` can't recognize `startLocation` index. Using `Mongo Compass` , I'm able to see all indexes that I've created except `startLocation:'2dsphere'.`

Here is the error that postman gives me below when I send request to `getDistances` method in controller:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "error": {
        "operationTime": "6791492473605586945",
        "ok": 0,
        "errmsg": "$geoNear requires a 2d or 2dsphere index, but none were found",
        "code": 27,
        "codeName": "IndexNotFound",
        "$clusterTime": {
            "clusterTime": "6791492473605586945",
            "signature": {
                "hash": "4LYCSBslSoLAoqj93bLXmpubBxs=",
                "keyId": "6779443539857113090"
            }
        },
        "name": "MongoError",
        "statusCode": 500,
        "status": "error"
    },
    "message": "$geoNear requires a 2d or 2dsphere index, but none were found",
    "stack": "MongoError: $geoNear requires a 2d or 2dsphere index, but none were found\n    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\timuc\\Downloads\\starter\\starter\\node_modules\\mongodb-core\\lib\\connection\\pool.js:443:61)\n    at Connection.emit (events.js:223:5)\n    at processMessage (C:\\Users\\timuc\\Downloads\\starter\\starter\\node_modules\\mongodb-core\\lib\\connection\\connection.js:364:10)\n    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\timuc\\Downloads\\starter\\starter\\node_modules\\mongodb-core\\lib\\connection\\connection.js:533:15)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)\n    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)\n    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)\n    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)\n    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:181:23)"
}
```

I tried to add `point: '2dsphere'` which was recognized by mongodb but I'm not satisfied. Because when I send request to method in controller that returns success but with empty array.

Here is the method which was triggered in controller:

```
exports.getDistances = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { latlng, unit } = req.params;
  const [lat, lng] = latlng.split(",");
  if (!lat || !lng) {
    new AppError( "Please provide latitude and longitude in the format lat,lng", 400);
  }

  const distances = await Tour.aggregate([
    {
      $geoNear: {
        near: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: [lng * 1, lat * 1]
        },
        distanceField: "distance"
      }
    }
  ]);

  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    data: {
      data: distances
    }
  });
});
```

also from router you can see how I send the request URL below

```
tourRouter.route('/distances/:latlng/unit/:unit').get(tourController.getDistances);
```

Comment: Is your Tour object pointing to the proper collection because based on your input this is working properly on my end. (MongoDB 4.2)

Comment: This link may be used for you in details.  http://laxmanchavda.blogspot.com/2018/08/mongodb-get-document-in-nearby-order.html

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that you are not using the proper collection. This is working for MongoDB 4.2.

Creating the index:

```
db.location.createIndex({
    startLocation: "2dsphere"
})
```

Indexes of that collection:

```
db.location.getIndexes()
[{
        "v": 2,
        "key": {
            "_id": 1
        },
        "name": "_id_",
        "ns": "stackoverflow.location"
    }, {
        "v": 2,
        "key": {
            "startLocation": "2dsphere"
        },
        "name": "startLocation_2dsphere",
        "ns": "stackoverflow.location",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion": 3
    }
]
```

Inserting some data:

```
db.location.insert({
    startLocation: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [40, 5],
        address: "Hellostreet 1",
        description: "Hello"
    }
})
```

Aggregate the collection:

```
db.location.aggregate([{
        $geoNear: {
            near: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [41, 6]
            },
            distanceField: 'distance'
        }
    }
])
```

The result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e404cdd13552bde0a0a9dc5"),
    "startLocation" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                    40,
                    5
            ],
            "address" : "Hellostreet 1",
            "description" : "Hello"
    },
    "distance" : 157065.62445348964
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm working on NodeJS using mongoose.So I should do all those model operations using schema not db.location.createIndex.Should be  schema.Index....

Comment: You can also see my project for more details on this repo https://github.com/timucincicek/natoursProject

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek there is nothing wrong creating the index manually. Actually even in mongoose docs they state that mongoose isn't an index management solution. It is clear that mongoose couldn't create the indexes, and you need to create the index yourself.